# Node.js Typescript how to assign Request.payload to self-defined interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, hapi.js

I have a node.js API in hapi.js framework. I want to create interfaces for user input payload. For example:

Route definition:

```
{
    path: "/sample",
    method: "POST",
    handler: myHandler,
    options: {
        validate: {
            payload: {
                number1: joi.number().required(),
                string1: joi.string().required(),
                number2: joi.number(),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
interface SampleInput {
    number1: number;
    string1: string;
    number2?: number;
}

const myHandler = async (request, h): Promise<string> => {
    const input: SampleInput = request.payload;

    // any works but really want to get rid of this
    const _input: any = request.payload;
    const input: SampleInput = _input;

    // Service body

    return "Hello World";
}
```

This code always shows some error like `Request.payload is not assignable to Sample`. The type of `Request.payload` is `string | object | Buffer | internal.Readable`. I tried with type guard `const input: SampleInput = (<object>request.payload);` but still get something like `{} is not assignable to Sample`.

How can I define a type and assign payload directly to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<object>` type assertion didn't work because `SampleInput` is not just some random object, and `object` basically designates an object in general, i.e. non-primitive type that doesn't have specific keys (see [this great explanation](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type)). `SampleInput` is a superset of `object`. `SampleInput` can be assigned to `object` variable but not vice versa.

Considering that it's known that `payload` is `SampleInput` because it was validated at runtime, it should be:

```
const input = <SampleInput>request.payload;
```

It's expected to work because `request.payload` is *string | **object** | Buffer | internal.Readable*, so it can be asserted as *SampleInput* (could require a hack like `<SampleInput><any>request.payload` otherwise).

Comment: Hi, is that syntax equivalent as `request.payload as SampleInput`?

Comment: @ErnestJones Yes, `as` is newer syntax that is generally more recommended because it needs no adjustments to be compatible with JSX.